# homomorphic image of prime and maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is the homomorphic image of a prime ideal always prime?
>   Is the homomorphic image of a maximal ideal always maximal?

---

Can someone help me please to check these questions please. thank you for your support.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: In general the image of an ideal under a ring homomorphism is not even an ideal in the codomain. If you're considering surjective homomorphisms, you should add the hypothesis to your question.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Consider the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$.

If $A\to B$ is a *surjective* ring homomorphism, then the image of a prime ideal of $A$ that contains the kernel of the map will necessarily be a prime ideal of $B$, and similarly for maximal ideals.

Comment: You need to assume that the prime/maximal ideal of $A$ contains the kernel of the homomorphism. Otherwise, consider the image of $(3)$ under $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/(2).$

Comment: @Ragib: Of course, thanks for catching my slip.

Comment: @RagibZaman what is the homomorphism you used explicitly from $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ ?

Comment: @SenoreBunuel The map that takes $n$ to $0$ is $n$ is even and $1$ if $n$ is odd.